# Bootstrap Offcanvas example in angular 4

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, bootstrap-4, off-canvas-menu

I am new developing with angular and I am trying to replicate this bootstrap *navbar* [example](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/offcanvas/) in my application. The problem is that the responsive of the *navbar* does not work when I pass it to angular. 
I installed all the necessary dependencies for this to work, but it does not work and I do not understand why.

This is an example that works perfectly, but that is built without using angular:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto mr-lg-0" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.4/holder.js" integrity="sha256-crfkMD0BL2TtiwpbIlXF/SVmGSvOtgbMM8GBkibVKyc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        'use strict'
        $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').on('click', function () {
          $('.offcanvas-collapse').toggleClass('open')
        })
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but when I translate this code to angular, it does not work. The specific part where I think the difference is found is in this:

```
<script>
 $(function () {
   'use strict'
    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').on('click', function () {
     $('.offcanvas-collapse').toggleClass('open')
   })
 })
</script>
```

My question is how does this part translate to angular?

Comment: Why do you think it needs translation as such?

Comment: because it is the only part that remains to be translated. My goal is to be able to replicate the mentioned example using angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the part of the function mentioned in the question was what I needed.

This is my angular component.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto mr-lg-0" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" (click)="toggle()">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my component.ts in angular:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery:any;
declare var $:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-dashboard-menu',
  templateUrl: './user-dashboard-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-dashboard-menu.component.css']
})
export class UserDashboardMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  toggle(){
    $('.offcanvas-collapse').toggleClass('open');
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The above shows a way of doing a translation of a Jquery function to an angular component!

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but I received an error in console saying `$ is not defined`. I have `$` and `jQuery` declared as you did. Any idea?.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this in rout terminal:

```
npm i bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

And then add this in polyfills.ts :

```
import 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap';
```